# How to use Saxon(XSLT 2.0 processor) in eclipse indigo with JAVA

Tags: java, eclipse, saxon

I have to use XSLT 2.0 processor for string manipulation functions like `replace()`. I have added the dependency for saxon in POM file and ran "mvn install" command. By doing this "saxon-9.1.0.8.jar" is added under "Referenced Libraries" folder.

In the code I have used `System.setProperty("javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory", "net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl");`

When I try to call the following line `TransformerFactory.newInstance("net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl", null);`
I am getting an error saying

```
javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactoryConfigurationError: Provider net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl not found.
```

If I try to call `new net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl();`, I get the error as `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/saxon/TransformerFactoryImpl`

Please let me know if I am missing something in configuring saxon with eclipse indigo.

Comment: When you look in the jar file, does it show the class?

Comment: You should use Saxon HE if you're using Maven. Get the latest from here http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.saxon/Saxon-HE

Comment: The messages all indicate that the Saxon jar file is not on the class path. But I don't know enough about configuring Eclipse-indigo to know why that might be the case.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you have included `saxon` jar in the build path. Then in your source code the following lines should work:

```
System.setProperty("javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory",
                   "net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl");
TransformerFactory tfactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Michael you have not included the Saxon jar file on your class path correctly . I guess there is an option in eclipse to add jar files by clicking on the project - build path- add jar (Something similar to this.) . Give it a try and build your workspace that might help.

Answer (score 0):

Simple Example below:

Make sure saxon9ee.jar is in your classpath

**movie.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<movies>
    <movie>
        <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
        <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>Columbia</company>
        <price>10.90</price>
        <year>1985</year>
    </movie>
    <movie>
        <title>Hide your heart</title>
        <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>CBS Records</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1988</year>
    </movie>
    <movie>
        <title>Greatest Hits</title>
        <artist>Dolly Parton</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>RCA</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1982</year>
    </movie>
    <movie>
        <title>Still got the blues</title>
        <artist>Gary Moore</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>Virgin records</company>
        <price>10.20</price>
        <year>1990</year>
    </movie>
    <movie>
        <title>Eros</title>
        <artist>Eros Ramazzotti</artist>
        <country>EU</country>
        <company>BMG</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1997</year>
    </movie>
    <movie>
        <title>One night only</title>
        <artist>Bee Gees</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>Polydor</company>
        <price>10.90</price>
        <year>1998</year>
    </movie>
</movies>
```

**movie.xsl**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <h2>Movies</h2>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                        <th style="text-align:left">Title</th>
                        <th style="text-align:left">Artist</th>
                        <th style="text-align:left">Country</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="movies/movie">
                        <xsl:sort select="country"></xsl:sort>

                        <!-- IF CONDITION -->
                        <xsl:if test="country='USA'">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="title" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="artist" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="country" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**SaxonDemo.java**

```
import java.io.File;

import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

public class SaxonDemo {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.setProperty("javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory", "net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl");
    transform("movie.xml", "movie.xsl");
  }

  public static void transform(String xmlFile, String xslFile) throws TransformerException,
      TransformerConfigurationException {

    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(new File(xslFile)));
    transformer.transform(new StreamSource(new File(xmlFile)), new StreamResult(System.out));
  }
}
```

**run in command line**

```
C:\Users\ranjiths>java -jar C:\ranjiths\T3\ws\XSLTDemo\lib\saxon9ee.jar C:\ranjiths\T3\ws\XSLTDemo\testdata\xml\movie.xml C:\ranjiths\T3\ws\XSLTDemo\testdata\xsl\movie.xsl
```

**output:**

```
<html>
   <body>
      <h2>Movies</h2>
      <table border="1">
         <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
            <th style="text-align:left">Title</th>
            <th style="text-align:left">Artist</th>
            <th style="text-align:left">Country</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Empire Burlesque</td>
            <td>Bob Dylan</td>
            <td>USA</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Greatest Hits</td>
            <td>Dolly Parton</td>
            <td>USA</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```